# Accessing multiple elements of a matrix in C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I have following Matlab code:

```
A = rand(4); % just for an example
B = A(1:3,1:2);
```

Thus B will be a 3x2 matrix and will contain elements of A starting from first row to third row and first column to second column. I could certainly do this in C++ with a for loop, but is there an easier way (like Matlab) to do this?

Comment: If you want a 3 by 2 matrix of integers in C++, you first need an [array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) of arrays of integers, then loop over the outer array and use e.g. [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) to generate the random numbers. If you want to use matrices in plain C++ there's no alternative to looping. You might want to search for libraries though, its very likely that [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) have something you can use. (However, note that asking for libraries is off-topic on SO.)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for something like the [Armadillo library](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html)

Check [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#syntax) the conversion table between Matlab/Octave and C++

Answer (score -1):

I suggest Eigen for working with matrixes http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page.